# MySql SET intersection

Tags: mysql

I have next database

```
|   ID   |  numbers   |
|--------|------------|
|    1   | 1,2,3      |
|    2   | 4,5,6      |
|    3   | 2,3,4      |
```

To retrieve all rows where `numbers` holds a given number is easy:

```
SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE FIND_IN_SET(3, numbers)
```

This returns row 1 and 3

But now I want to pass an array/set of numbers and want to retrieve all entries where at least one number occurs in `numbers`, i.e. where the intersect of both sets is not empty
Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE SET_INTERSECT('2,4', numbers)!=NULL
```

This should return all rows because every row holds 2 and/or 4.

The above doesn't work. Is this possible in mysql?

Thanks!

Comment: First normal form! All I'm saying.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use OR ?

```
SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, numbers) or FIND_IN_SET(4, numbers)
```

Comment: Actually this is how I do it now. In this simplified example it makes sense to do it like that but in my real application the first set can grow to 30 numbers or more. Besides the fact that such an expanded query won't win a beauty contest I'm not sure if it is efficient.

Comment: for efficiency, pls refer to @rmunoz answer. you would have to redesign the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the table structure to:

```
ID | NUMBERS

 1 | 1
 1 | 2
 1 | 3
 2 | 4
 2 | 5
 ...

SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table WHERE numbers = 2 OR numbers = 4
/*or...*/
/*WHERE numbers IN (2, 4)*/
```